# Restrict type of xsd:any to xsd:string only?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

So I'm writing a new XSD and I've come across a little issue. Now I'll admit I'm not the best with these, but I would have thought what I have done should have worked but it doesn't.

What I am after is I have an element called `extraInfo` and this element can have up to 42 child elements with any name but only of type string. Here is what I have:

```
<xsd:element name="extraInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xsd:annotation>
       <xsd:documentation></xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="42" type="xsd:string" />
       </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I would have thought that as long as I am passing in the type as `xsd:string` it should only accept this type in these elements, but the element name can be named whatever it wants. However I am getting an error under the `type` attribute of

> s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'type' cannot appear in element 'any'.

How can I get it so I can pass in 42 elements of unknown name but have them as type string?

**Edit**

So basically we might have one client pass us the following

```
<extraInfo>
    <logoUrl>http://www.google.com/logo.png</logoUrl>
    <cssUrl>http://www.google.com/main.css</cssUrl>
</extraInfo>
```

but another client pass us

```
<extraInfo>
    <headerText>Hello World</headerText>
    <footerText>Goodbye World</footerText>
</extraInfo>
```

We can't guarantee what the element names are called.  All we can guarantee is the type and that is string and that we will allow up to 42 elements to be passed in. (No reason for 42 except its the answer to everything right? Picked out of a hat basically.)

Comment: can you add a possible dataexample?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger give me a minute and I'll make an example something I might expect.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger I've added some data examples hope it helps. I was under the impression that if you used `element` you needed to provide a `name` attribute. What happens if I miss the `name` attribute off will I be able to pass in any element name?

Comment: I don't think this can be represented in XML Schema 1.0, but if you can use 1.1 then you could have an `xs:any` without specifying a type, then an assertion of `not(*/*)` on the `complexType` to disallow grandchild elements under the `extraInfo`

Comment: I can't get this right either. i used to be quite good at this but that was some time ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.1

See @IanRoberts fine suggestion in the comments regarding asserting that no grandchild elements exist under the children of `extraInfo`.

### XSD 1.0

If you want more control over the type of the `extraInfo` child elements, you'll have to specify their names a priori.

**Attributes**

Or, why not leverage the fact that **attribute values already are constrained not to have subelements** and use `xsd:anyAttribute` instead:

```
  <xsd:element name="extraInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

Users could then add `extraInfo` along these lines:

```
<extraInfo
     logoUrl="http://www.google.com/logo.png"
     cssUrl="http://www.google.com/main.css"/>
```

and

```
<extraInfo
    headerText="Hello World"
    footerText="Goodbye World"/>
```

which would be natural given that you wish to allow only string values.

**Elements** (update per OP question in comments)

If the max of 42 constraint is important to you, you could go meta with a structure such as

```
<extraInfo>
    <item name="logoUrl" value="http://www.google.com/logo.png"/>
    <item name="cssUrl" value="http://www.google.com/main.css"/>
</extraInfo>
```

Then you could restrict the number of `item` elements trivially in XSD 1.0 via `@maxOccurs`.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution. Can I restrict the number of attributes passed in? So I can restrict it to say a max of 42 attributes?

Comment: Restricting attribute count: In XSD 1.1, yes, using assertions; in XSD 1.0, you'd have to check that out-of-band.   If restricting max number of user items is really important, you might consider going meta with `item` elements with user-defined `@name` and `@value` attributes.  Then you could easily restrict the maximum number of `items`.  Answer updated with example.

Comment: I think your answer is the closest I'm going to get withot changing to `XML Schema 1.1` so going to accept. Thank you.