# Regular Expression that stops HTML Tags

Tags: regex, xsd

So as part of my xsd schema that I am writing, I am adding elements that take in String content but what I want to do is stop the user from entering things like HTML tags. So I thought the best way of doing this would be to add a restrictive pattern so I want to pass in a regular expression that will stop users from passing in HTML Tags but my regular expression knowledge is pretty poor actually its beyond poor.

So far I have this

```
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="42" type="type:extraInfoType" >
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>


<xsd:complexType name="extraInfoType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="" /> // So I want a regular expression here.
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

So my question is what would the regular expression be to stop users entering HTML Tags?

I've seen something like `<(img|a)[^>]*>(?<content>[^<]*)<` but from my minimal understanding of Regular Expressions is that this is for checking for the `<img>` and `<a>` tags only. I want to check for all tags.

I also thought I could possibly just do `[a-zA-Z0-9]` will this make it so the element only accepts characters and numbers and no special characters? What if I want to accept certain special characters like `"`, `'`, `@`, `,` ,`.`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `£` and `%`?

Comment: What you want is hard to achieve correctly. So you could use something like this `<[/!]?\S+[\s\S]*?>` but don't be surprised if it messes things up :)

Comment: @HamZa What exactly will that regex expression do for me? My regular expression knowledge is shocking so I'm not actually sure what that will do.

Comment: Actually check this expression out `<[\/!]?\S[\s\S]*?>`. Here's an [*online demo*](https://regex101.com/r/hH1oV1/1) where you can test and read an explanation.

Comment: @HamZa unfortunately I can't use `<[\/!]?\S[\s\S]*?>` by the looks of it. Works fine in https://regex101.com/ but when I drop it into the `<xsd:pattern value="<[\/!]?\S[\s\S]*?>" />` we get the following error `"The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "xsd:pattern" must not contain the '<' character."`

Comment: If you're using either of the XSD 1.0 solutions from the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28748071/290085) to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28746575/290085), you don't have to check for tags because ***attribute values already cannot contain tags***.

Comment: You may, however, still want to [sanitize your input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling) at the interface-level to ***before*** you add user input to the XML.   Some JavaScript ideas for doing so can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2794137/290085).

Answer (score 0):

What about using [character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) like \S (non-whitespace characters)?